# Print file without entering user-ID

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I have an excel file I want to print from a macro.
this i my code

```
ActiveSheet.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="\\printer name".
```

I get now a box where I need to enter a user-id. The user ID is already entered and then I have to press OK, but I do not want to have that box. I just want to print this automatically.

PS. I cannot chance the print options, I am in a business environment...

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, perhaps? I can't say for sure without seeing the code.

Comment: Sub invoer()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim STDprinter As String

STDprinter = Application.ActivePrinter
ActiveSheet.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="\\SRPGEN23055\PR251419"
Application.ActivePrinter = STDprinter

End Sub

Comment: It isn't working. your code was already in my macro ...